# Follow current window in screen -x

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, gnu-screen

Using `screen -x` (after connecting over ssh) from a second computer is a great way to follow what someone is doing in a terminal.

However, if the first person changes the screen window (`C-a p` or `C-a n`), the second screen (`screen -x`) stays in the same window.

Is there a way to make `screen -x` follow the window opened in the other screen?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no. You could do some hackery with "at", to mirror window change commands to all connected displays, but that's dumb, in the sense that the command is mirrored, not the effect.

For example, with `bind p at % prev` you change `C-a p` to send the "prev" command not just to the current display (and go to the previous window), but to all displays (the `%` argument: `<matchstring>%` means that *matchstring* gets prefix-matched against the display names, and the empty string matches all of them). Which works fine if everyone is looking at the same window; anyone hitting `C-a p` will move everyone one window back. Mid-keystroke, possibly, and if two attached users are on different windows at the time either of them hits that command, something hilarious happens.

You can try setting the display's caption or hardstatus to include the window flags, which will at least indicate whether the current window is shared; to find out where everyone else currently is, use the `displays` command, which unfortunately doesn't have a key for "switch to this window".